# swift で hitTest(_, with event) が呼び出されない

Tags: swift, ios

前面のUIWindowと後面のUIWindowがある状態で、
タップイベントを前面のWindowをスルーさせて、
後面のWindowで処理したいため、前面のWindowを
以下のように実装しました。

```
class FrontWindow : UIWindow {
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        var hitTestView = super.hitTest(point, with: event)
        print("hitTest = Hit!")
        return nil
    }
}
```

FrontWindowの生成は以下のように行っております。

```
frontWindow = UIWindow()
frontWindow?.frame = window!.frame
frontWindow?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

期待値としては、画面のタップで、

```
FrontWindow.hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?)
```

が呼び出されることなのですが、動作確認してみると、
画面をタップしても`FrontWindow.hitTest`が呼び出されません。

何か足りない処理などありますでしょうか。
宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「FrontWindowの生成は以下のように」のところ、`frontWindow = UIWindow()`とありますから、生成しているのは`FrontWindow`ではなく`UIWindow`ですね。

Comment: ああ、何て凡ミスを・・・。ご指摘ありがとうございます。